# Getting mixed results while trying to calculate Jaccard coefficiency in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene, scoring

I am trying to get a Jaccard based score using Lucene.
I have succeeded in getting the number of terms of each document and i only need to find the number of terms of my query that are found in each doc.
While searching Lucene's Javadocs i came across

```
score.freq()
```

this method according to the Javadoc

> Returns number of matches for the current document. This returns a
>   float (not int) because SloppyPhraseScorer discounts its freq
>   according to how "sloppy" the match was.

I am testing it with a very simple doc i created that has the following

> cat cat cat dog bird snake

When my query is : **cat dog**

i get a score.freq() equal with 2 (which is the expected)

When my query is : **cat**

i get a score.freq() equal with 3

Anyone knows why this is happening?
Tested it with bigger queries also, and i get correct results. Also when my query was **dog** (Which has a frequency of 1 in the doc)
I got the expected result of score.freq() equal to 1

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Answer (score 1):

Scorer.freq() is an expert api whose result depends upon the scorer in question.

The differences you are seeing is because freq() for a boolean scorer represents the number of matchers (e.g. boolean clauses) that matched, whereas for a term scorer, its the number of occurrences in the document for that term.

So you need to collect freq() from the correct scorers (e.g. the boolean scorer or its leaves) depending upon which one you need. In 3.x releases this is a visitor API, but in 4.x releases you can navigate the scorer hierarchy iteratively via getChildren(). This is typically the kind of thing you would do in your Collector.setNextReaderMethod, saving references only to the scorers you care about so that your actual collect() is very fast.

NOTE: I feel its fair to mention that this feature is very new and advanced and has some bugs. In some cases there are patches available, but just hasn't been the time to write up good tests :(

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3505

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2686